# line missing from downloaded image of d3 scatter plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, plot

I am using d3 scatter plot with correlation line. Everything is working fine. When I added download button it's able to download image but line is missing from the image. I am using following function to download the Image.

```
d3.select("#downloadplot").on("click", function(){  
     var html = d3.select("svg") 
    .attr("version", 1.1)
    .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
    .node( ).parentNode.innerHTML;   //node().parentNode.innerHTML;

    //console.log(html);

 var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(html);
var image = new Image;
image.src = imgsrc;

image.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
context.fillRect(0,0,image.width,image.height);
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = "sampleidvgraph.png";
a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click().attr('target', '_blank');
}
});
```

link of original scatter plot example:
http://prcweb.co.uk/lab/what-makes-us-happy/
here is downloaded Image
[image: here is downloaded Image:]
Original scatter plot
[image: Original scatter plot]

code that append line:

```
   // Best fit line (to appear behind points)
     d3.select('svg g.chart')
   .append('line')
   .attr('id', 'bestfit');
```

and

```
       // Fade in
           d3.select('#bestfit')
             .style('opacity', 0)
            .attr({'x1': xScale(x1), 'y1': yScale(y1), 'x2': xScale(x2), 'y2': yScale(y2)})
            .transition()
            .duration(1500)
            .style('opacity', 1);
```

Comment: Please share the portion of **your** code that appends that line.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I updated code.

Comment: And why is that line red? Do you have any CSS for that line?

Comment: yes, path {
 fill: #CED8B6;
}

line {
 stroke: #555;
 stroke-width: 2px;
}

line#bestfit {
 stroke: red;
 stroke-width: 2px;
}

Comment: That's the problem, just confirming it before posting the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the function you're using to download the SVG relies on the SVG content only, set the `stroke` and the `stroke-width` in the D3 code, not in the CSS:

```
d3.select('#bestfit')
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .style("stroke", "red")//set the colour here
    .style("stroke-width", 2)//set the width here
    .attr({
        'x1': xScale(x1),
        'y1': yScale(y1),
        'x2': xScale(x2),
        'y2': yScale(y2)
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .style('opacity', 1);
```

Comment: It worked, so we need to define style in d3 not in css.

Comment: In that case yes, because the "download" function just gets the SVG content. In the browser the line shows up read because the browser uses the CSS to style all the elements that appear on the screen (if present in the CSS, of course).

Comment: *"...the line shows up **red**..."* damn you autocorrect.

Comment: I want to ask something from above example, if you have any idea, Is it possible to delete one point by click in graph and then redraw the line?

Comment: Since this is a different issue, please post a new question. Also, as your issue here was fixed, please consider marking the answer, so future users will see that it worked.